# Existing answer detected as improperly formatted code while trying to edit

Tags: support, edits, code-formatting, quality-filter

I'm trying to edit the [`regex` community-wiki reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075), but any change I make gives me the error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

There is no such improperly formatted code, and this error occurs **even when the post is exactly the same as how it is already** (to get the message to appear, make some changes and then undo them).

---

In case a moderator or user with higher reputation is able to override this problem, the edit I wanted to make was to add the Python `ASCII` regex flag to the table of flags, specifically with this patch:

```
--- so_orig.md  2021-05-29 18:17:45.289263676 +0100
+++ so_edited.md    2021-05-29 18:19:00.371708528 +0100
@@ -89,6 +89,7 @@
 
 | flag | modifier                  | flavors |
 | ---- | ------------------------- | ------- |
+| `a`  | [ASCII][h17]              | [tag:python]
 | `c`  | [current position][h6]    | [tag:perl]
 | `e`  | [expression][h7]          | [tag:php] [tag:perl]
 | `g`  | [global][h1]              | most
@@ -283,6 +284,7 @@
   [h14]:https://stackoverflow.com/q/16367404
   [h15]:https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636
   [h16]:https://javascript.info/regexp-sticky
+  [h17]:https://stackoverflow.com/a/61203075
   [i1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22187948
   [i2]: https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078
   [i3]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008790
```

Comment: I've made the edit

Comment: @pppery: Did you use some kind of workaround?

Comment: I didn't do anything special; I think the code formatting restriction may only apply to low-rep users.